# cannot resolve method createSpeechRecognizer()

Tags: android, android-fragments, speech-recognition

I want to add speechRecognizer to my fragment page but, what I got is `cannot resolve method createSpeechRecognizer()` and here is my code maybe anyone can help me.

```
final SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer = (SpeechRecognizer) SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(context);
final SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer =
        (SpeechRecognizer) SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer();
final EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
final Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html#createSpeechRecognizer(android.content.Context)):

You can use:

- `SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer (Context context)`
- `SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer (Context context, ComponentName serviceComponent)`

**Remove in your code** the second line:

```
final SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer =
        (SpeechRecognizer) SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer();
```